# hibernate mapping create table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I wrote a mapping as like below:

```
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true" default-lazy="false">
    <class name="com.saman.entity.hibernate.EmployeeEntity"
           table="Employee" optimistic-lock="version">

        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" >
            <column name="Id" />
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <timestamp name="version" source="db"/>
        <property  name="firstName">
            <column name="FirstName" sql-type="nvarchar(300)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastName">
            <column name="LastName" sql-type="nvarchar(300)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="employeeType">
            <column name="EmployeeType" sql-type="nvarchar(300)"/>
        </property>
        <!--
        <set name="shifts" table="Shifts" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="Id" not-null="true"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.saman.entity.hibernate.ShiftEntity"/>
        </set>
        -->
        <properties name="u1" unique="true">
            <property name="firstName"/>
            <property name="lastName"/>
            <property name="employeeType"/>
        </properties>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

when I run my application an error occurs like below:

2012-05-15 17:12:38,651 -- WARN -- Unsuccessful schema statement: create table Employee (Id integer not null auto_increment, version datetime not null, FirstName nvarchar(300), LastName nvarchar(300), EmployeeType nvarchar(300), primary key (Id), unique (firstName, lastName, employeeType))
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1749)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1666)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:64)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.executeSchemaStatement(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:1115)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.executeSchemaScript(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean$1.doInHibernate(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:942)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.updateDatabaseSchema(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:935)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterSessionFactoryCreation(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:883)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)

what is the problem with it?

Im using mysql and i run it on MAMP.

Comment: Post the full stack trace, and post the code causing this exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

This error means that your unique index (firstName, lastName, employeeType) is more than 1000 bytes which is the maximum. From mysql documentation

```
"UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character"
```

Therefore you can see that you have three fields of 300 length so you may have an index of size 300* 3 * 3 = 2700 > 1000

Answer (score 2):

There is known issue with MyISAM engine. You can try this [link](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=192872609) to change the engine to InnoDB: